# TextView no coloca Texto en childFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

Quiero mandar un numero de un Texfield que se encuentra en un Fragment a un  TextView de un childFragment, pero no me muestra el numero ingresado

Intente crear una funcion en el childFragment y llamarla desde el fragment pero no logre hacerlo, utilice este codigo [Call an activity method from a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659747/call-an-activity-method-from-a-fragment)

estoy usando AndroidX y Kotlin

El codigo de mi Fragment

```
private var btnSearch: Button? = null
var numero: TextView?=null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
    btnSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch)
    btnSearch!!.setOnClickListener { validar()  }
    numero = view.findViewById(R.id.idNum)
    return view
}


fun validar(){
    if(num.text.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(activity, "ingresa un numero " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }else{
        numero?.setText(num.text)
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Resultados, InformacionFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit()
    }
}
```

y el childFragment

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_informacion, container, false)
}
```

El layout de mi Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SearchFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="end|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="Escriba el numero"
        android:inputType="number" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buscar">

    </Button>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Resultados"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="end|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

y el Layout de mi childFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".InformacionFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Numero" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idNum"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sin resultados"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nombre" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sin resultados"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Logre que mostrara el numero pero debo crear el childfragment primero y después colocar un numero y este se coloca, pero si no lo creo antes se cierra la aplicación

```
private var btnSearch: Button? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
    btnSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch)
    btnSearch!!.setOnClickListener { validar()  }
    return view
}


fun validar(){
    if(num.text.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(activity, "ingresa un numero " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Resultados, InformacionFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit()
    }else{
        idNum.setText(num.text)
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Resultados, InformacionFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay muchas maneras de resolver tu problema.

Lo que pasa es que estas haciendo replace por un nuevo Fragment cada vez que haces click. Pero no pasando el valor.

En la funcion `validar()` debes pasarle el valor. Una forma es utilizando los argumentos:

```
fun validar(){
    if(num.text.isEmpty())
        Toast.makeText(activity, "ingresa un numero " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    else{
        idNum.setText(num.text)
        var informacionFragment = InformacionFragment()
        var args = Bundle()
        args.putString("num", num.text)
        informacionFragment.setArguments(args)
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Resultados, 
            informacionFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Luego en tu childFragment, debes hacer set del numero:

en el `onCreateView`:

```
val num = getArguments()?.getString("num", "")
```

y ya este valor, debes setearlo en el childFragment a su TextView correspondiente.

Ten en cuenta que cada vez que haces replace, estas creando un nuevo fragment y por ende corriendo un nuevo ciclo de vida del Fragment.

Comment: Intente implementar el código pero me aparece "Classifier 'Bundle' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here"